# Understanding Rails Controller Request Format: "Processing by MyController#action as FORMAT"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actioncontroller

In all likelihood, this question reveals my gross misunderstandings of Rails, HTTP, and the internet.

### Problem

I have a request hitting my server from a "transparent redirect" via Stripe API.  The request is coming in as HTML format.  I want to respond to it in JS format in an AJAX-esque way. My code looks like this:

```
def create
       .... other code ....
    render "attendances/create", formats: [:js]
end
```

I have a view file "attendances/create.js.erb."  This successfully sends a response, but rather than the response executing the JS, the JS is instead rendered as HTML.  It thus looks like plaintext JS.

Thank you for taking the time to consider this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the request headers, Your ajax request must have accept request headers of javascript instead of default html, for it to allow/execute the js response directly.

See datatype [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , it should be `script`

Comment: This led me in the correct direction, which was really spending more time understanding HTTP requests.  For some reason calling jquery's .submit() on a remote: true form was overriding Rails's :remote => :true functionality.  Figured that out by inspecting the headers more closely.  Ended up just calling my own $.ajax() rather than using $.submit().